# Unable to grep file in Ubuntu, matching lines are blank?

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I have a CSV file which is parsed by a bash script in order to find the position of a given ID within the file, as a means of tracking progress via JMeter.

The specific line I'm having trouble with consists of this code:

```
egrep -n -C 2 '49156$'
```

Previously I've run the script with no problem, however I think something funny has happened to the character encoding or the end line characters. As now when I run this line I get no return.

If I change the regex to check for an extra character, such as `'49156.$'` then I get the following in OSX and Ubuntu:

**OSX:**

```
1307-node/49150
1308-node/49153
1309:node/49156
1310-node/49159
1311-node/49162
```

**Ubuntu:**

```
1307-node/49150
1308-node/49153

1310-node/49159
1311-node/49162
```

I need the script to run on an Ubuntu server, so I really need to get it functioning on that, however as I said, the script has run fine with previous CSVs, I'm really not sure how this most recent CSV has become altered.

If I look at the file in VIM using `:set list` I see the following:

```
node/49153$
node/49156$
node/49159$
node/49162$
node/49165$
```

I thought to check for numeric block instead of the end line character, using the pattern: `'49156[^0-9]'` however this still produces the same result:

```
1307-node/49150
1308-node/49153

1310-node/49159
1311-node/49162
```

Other than the above, I'm not really sure what to test for next. Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: It definitely hasn't touched a windows machine, however now you mention it, the description in vim does mention `"paths.csv" [dos] 56159L, 878008C` at the bottom, god knows how. I'll give that a try, thanks!

Comment: @ruakh That did it, thanks :D. Post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: To be clear, the file was generated by a MySQL single column query, using the `-B -e 'SELECT...'` command line syntax. I've run it before I'm sure to generate other CSVs without this problem, clearly something about my process changed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your file might be using CRLF (carriage-return + line-feed) for line endings, instead of just LF (line-feed). (This might happen if, for example, your file was ever edited on a Windows machine.) So, I'd suggest running `dos2unix` on it, to remove any stray carriage-returns, and see if that fixes it.